# Разница в приведении типов (int) a и int (a)

Tags: c++

Есть ли какая-то принципиальная/важная разница между приведением типов:

```
int (a);
(int) a;
```

Знаю что второй способ (в отличии от первого) возможен также в `Cи`, но в остольном они, вроде как, эквивалентны. Но, недавно, прослушивая один курс по программированию на `c++` узнал о принципе, используемом в `c++`, который гласит: все, что похоже на объявление функции - и есть функция. `int (a)` - похоже на объявление функции, в отличии от `(int) a` - которое похоже на объявление переменной.

Comment: Вот, посмотрите - https://ideone.com/L6PcsF

Comment: У них есть принципиальное сходство - ни то, ни другое в C++ использовать не следует.

Comment: первый вариант больше похож на вызов конструктора типа `int`